# How to add after plugin /vendor/magento/module-customer-graph-ql/Model/Resolver/CreateCustomer.php resolve() method?

Tags: magento2

How to add after plugin

```
/vendor/magento/module-customer-graph-ql/Model/Resolver/CreateCustomer.php
```

resolve() method ?

**etc/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CustomerGraphQl\Model\Resolver\CreateCustomer">
        <plugin name="segment_create_account_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CreateAccount" />
    </type>
</config>
```

CreateAccount.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class CreateAccount
{

    protected $logger;
    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    public function afterResolve(\Magento\CustomerGraphQl\Model\Resolver\CreateCustomer $subject, $result,$context, $info) {

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/CustomerRRegisterplugin1.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $this->logger($subject);
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/CustomerRRegisterplugin2.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $this->logger($context);

    }

}
```

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: The issue is that, i am not getting the customer object here.

Comment: is this working for you?

Answer (score -1):

please check the following resources to have a better grasp on how plugins are created:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#after-methods
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-plugin-interceptor.html